# Checking all array values at once

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a simple way to check if all values in array are equal to each other?

In this case, it would return false:

```
$array[0] = 'yes';
$array[1] = 'yes';
$array[2] = 'no';
```

And in this case, true:

```
$array[0] = 'yes';
$array[1] = 'yes';
$array[2] = 'yes';
```

So, yeah, is there a function/method to check all array values at once?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't think it was a very interesting question but there is a cool variety of answers. Nice.

Comment: @Hans Agreed, every answer has got it's own unique twist, very interesting results!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Not a single function, but the same could be achieved easily(?) with:

```
count(array_keys($array, 'yes')) == count($array)
```

Comment: From all of provided solutions this was the easiest to understand, provides most functionality and is really simple! +1, accepted. Huge bonus for that `yes` check.

Comment: array_keys is indeed better than array_count_values, because you also can check for array/object elements and enforce strict comparison when desired

Comment: don't forget to set the strict parameter when your value is something like 0 --- array_keys($array, 0, true)

Answer (score 9):

another possible option

```
if(count(array_unique($array)) == 1)
```

Comment: Most elegant and smartest. Of course, `count()` must be `1` with [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) because it "returns a new array without duplicate values."

Answer (score 2):

```
if($a === array_fill(0, count($a), end($a))) echo "all items equal!";
```

or better

```
if(count(array_count_values($a)) == 1)...
```

Answer (score 1):

"All values the same" is equivalent to "all values equal to the first element", so I'd do something like this:

```
function array_same($array) {
  if (count($array)==0) return true;

  $firstvalue=$array[0];
  for($i=1; $i<count($array); $i++) {
      if ($array[$i]!=$firstvalue) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(count(array_unique($array)) === count($array)) {  
  // all items in $array are the same
}else{
  // at least one item is different
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another way to go about it, using `array_diff` with lists

In my case, I had to test against arrays that had all empty strings:

```
$empty_array = array('','','');  // i know ahead of time that array has three elements
$array_2d = array();
for($array_2d as $arr)
  if(array_diff($arr,$empty_arr)) // 
       do_stuff_with_non_empty_array()
```