# Does PHP have an equivalent to Python's all()

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, functional-programming

Python has a nice `all()` ([doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)) method that returns true if all elements in an iterable are true, which is equivalent to:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

Is there a similarly nice way to do this in PHP?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829780/checking-all-array-values-at-once

Comment: Can't you just write that function in php? The shortcircuit behaviour is important for performance, and for ininite iterables.

Comment: Of course I could write it in PHP. But I prefer to use built-in functions when they are appropriate. Less code is more.

Comment: I don't understand why this question gets downvoted. It is concise and includes sample code and a doc link for those not familiar with the python function.

Comment: See also: [What is PHP's equivalent of JavaScript's "array.every()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156664/what-is-phps-equivalent-of-javascripts-array-every) (JS `some` and Python `all` are virtually identical)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Closest to it may be [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), if no true element are found it will return empty array that evaluates to false.

On the second thought it's more like pythons `any()`. To emulate `all()` you will need `if(array_filter($array) == $array)` or even `if(array_filter($array) == $array && $array)` to exclude empty array.

Comment: Thanks! This is much better than the for loop I have been using for this.

Comment: `all([])` is `true` in Python2 and 3, so you should not use the `&& $array` part to mimic Python.

Comment: This does not short-circuit so is much more expensive than Python's version. Your best bet is to write a short-circuiting loop version and put it in a function for reuse.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such function, but you can achieve the same effect with:

```
count(array_keys($array, 'yes')) == count($array)
```

Comment: Not really, this doesn't shortcircuit

Answer (score 0):

If all your values are boolean, this would be a simpler approach:

```
in_array(true,$array)
```