# What is PHP's equivalent of JavaScript's "array.every()"?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm currently trying to port some JavaScript over to PHP. However, I can't seem to find PHP's equivalent to the JavaScript `array.every()` function. I found PHP's `each()` function, but it doesn't seem to be exactly what I need.

Comment: plain ol' for loop, break out of it when the tested condition is false

Comment: Does `every` check if every element satisfies a predicate? Sometimes it's called `all`.

Comment: you say in a comment below that you are not very good with PHP, but if you are good with javascript, look at the [Array#every polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Polyfill) code and convert that to PHP - perhaps?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a for loop with an early return.

PHP does not have a native function that performs the same function as Javascript's array#every.

Answer (score 11):

Answers on this page are incomplete and change the semantics of `every` (JS) / `all` (Python) and similar functions from other languages. Mapping and reducing are incorrect  because they visit every element regardless of their truth value.

We need something that supports a callback for an arbitrary predicate and features early bailout upon locating the first element that fails the predicate function. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45156849/6243352) comes close because it offers early bailout but fails to provide a callback predicate.

We might as well write `some`/`any` while we're at it.

```
<?php

function array_every(array $arr, callable $predicate) {
    foreach ($arr as $e) {
        if (!call_user_func($predicate, $e)) {
             return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function array_any(array $arr, callable $predicate) {
    return !array_every($arr, fn($e) => !call_user_func($predicate, $e));
}

// sample predicate
function is_even(int $e) {
    return $e % 2 === 0;
}

var_dump(array_every([0, 1, 2, 3], "is_even")); // => bool(false)
var_dump(array_every([0, 2], "is_even")); // => bool(true)
var_dump(array_any([1, 2], "is_even")); // => bool(true)
var_dump(array_any([1, 3], "is_even")); // => bool(false)
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `foreach()`:

```
function allEven(array $values) 
{
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        if (1 === $value % 2) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

$data = [
    1,
    42,
    9000,
];

$allEven = allEven($data);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

**Note** `foreach` is better than using `array_reduce()` because evaluation will stop once a value has been found that doesn't satisfy the specification.

Comment: Pretty good answer because it (a) has a complete code example and (b) has early bailout but it could be improved to [accept a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67111853/6243352) instead of hardcoding the predicate. I'm not sure why you bother linking to `array_reduce` documentation--that function isn't appropriate for this purpose (as you state!) and you (correctly!) don't use it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Php array_every function

```
function array_every($array,$callback)
{

   return  !in_array(false,  array_map($callback,$array));
}


array_every([1,2,3],function($n){
     return $n>0;
});
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer because, even if it's a well-written solution, it doesn't work the same way as "every". "every" does early-return, when a falsy value was encountered (no further callbacks will be called). This one will all callbacks, regardless if it encountered a falsy value in one of them.

Comment: maybe  t dont think performance ,I didn't think about it,  just ı show how make  it of course you are  right ...

Comment: Note foreach is better than using array_reduce() because evaluation will stop once a value has been found that doesn't satisfy the specification.

ABOVE NOTE

Comment: It's not only performance, if the function passed to every has side-effects, it will also trigger those side-effects, an actual every-function does not :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function.

Comment: This method is also designed to be destructive, altering your array values.

Comment: `array_reduce` is fine (I use it plenty), but you should keep it in mind as your "when all else fails" function. It will scan your entire array every time, but `Array#every` should stop running as soon as on callback returns falsey.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```php
function array_every(array $array, callable $fn) {
  return (bool)array_product(array_map($fn, $array));
}
```

Check it online: https://3v4l.org/1D1Ao

It is not optimized and is just a proof of concept. For production I would use a `foreach` to return `false` on the first item that does not pass the test.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared this solution to be close to [JavaScript's `Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) as much as possible.

##### Proposed custom function:

Description:

The `array_every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

The `array_every()` method executes the provided `$callback` function once for each element present in the array until it finds the one where `$callback`returns a falsy value. If such an element is found, the  `array_every()` method immediately returns false. Otherwise, if `$callback` returns a truthy value for all elements, every returns true.

***Note:** Calling this method on an empty array will return true for any condition!*

The `array_every()` method does not mutate the array on which it is called.

```php
array_every(array $array, string|callable $callback, null|string|object $thisArg = null): bool
```

##### Parameters:

*$array*

The array to iterate over.

*$callback*

A callback function to test for each element, taking four arguments:

*$value* - The current *value* of the element being processed in the array.

*$key* (Optional) - The current *key* of the element being processed in the array.

*$index* (Optional) - The index of the current element being processed in the array.

*$array* (Optional) - The array being traversed.

*$thisArg* (Optional)

A value to use as `$this` when executing the `$callback` function.

##### Return value:

`true` if the `$callback` function returns a truthy value for every array element. Otherwise, `false`.

##### The array_every() function:

```php
function array_every(array $array, string|callable $callback, null|string|object $thisArg = null): bool
{
    $index = 0;

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        $condition = false;

        if (is_null($thisArg)) {
            $condition = call_user_func_array($callback, [$value, $key, $index, $array]);
        } else if (is_object($thisArg) || (is_string($thisArg) && class_exists($thisArg))) {
            $condition = call_user_func_array([$thisArg, $callback], [$value, $key, $index, $array]);
        } else if (is_string($thisArg) && !class_exists($thisArg)) {
            throw new TypeError("Class '$thisArg' not found");
        }

        if (!$condition)
            return false;
        $index++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

##### Example 1 (Simple callback function):

```php
$isEven = fn($v) => ($v % 2 === 0);

var_export(array_every([2, 8, 16, 36], $isEven)); // true
```

##### Example 2:

If a `$thisArg` parameter is provided to the `array_every()` method, it will be used as the `$callback`'s `$this` value. Otherwise, the value `null` will be used as its `$this` value.

```php
class Helper
{
    public function isOlderThan18(int $value): bool
    {
        return $value > 18;
    }

    public static function isVowel(string $character): bool
    {
        return in_array($character, ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']);
    }

}
```

##### Example 2a) Static class method call:

You may pass the *fully qualified class name* in the `$thisArg` argument if the class in question is declared under a namespace.

```php
var_export(array_every(["a", "u", "e"], "isVowel", "Helper")); // true
```

##### Example 2b) Object method call:

The `$thisArg` argument can be an object as well.

```php
var_export(array_every(["Peter" => "35", "Ben" => "16", "Joe" => "43"], "isOlderThan18", (new Helper))); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

**I wrote these codes first:**

```
function array_every(callable $callback, array $array) {
    $matches = [];
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if ($callback($item)) {
            $matches[] = true;
        } else {
            $matches[] = false;
        }
    }
    if (in_array(false, $matches)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**And then wrote the mini version of it:**

```
function array_every(callable $callback, array $array) {
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if (!$callback($item)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$array = [1, 2, 3];
$result = array_every(function($item) {
    return $item == 3; // Check if all items are 3 or not (This part is like JS)
}, $array);

echo $result; // Returns false, but returns true if $array = [3, 3, 3]
```

**So both versions works well**

And you got the answer! :)

Comment: I'd drop the first version. You don't want to visit every element of the array. If you have 1 million items and the first one fails the test, bail out immediately. Second version is good but has [already been posted before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67111853/6243352).

Comment: @ggorlen yeah but my second version is a little bit different and shorter 

Answer (score -1):

Here's another option (really, a lot of the array functions can be used fairly similarly):

```
$bool = !empty(array_filter(['my', 'test', 'array'], function ($item) {
    return $item === 'array';
}));
```

or for PHP7.4+, using arrow functions:

```
$bool = !empty(array_filter(['my', 'test', 'array'], fn($item) => $item === 'array'));
```

... which looks close-ish to JS:

```
let bool = ['my', 'test', 'array'].every(item => item === 'array'));
```

And broken out:

```
function array_every(array $array, callable $callback) {
    return !empty(array_filter($array, $callback));
}

$myArr = ['my', 'test', 'array'];
$myTest = fn($item) => $item === 'array'; // PHP7.4+
$bool = array_every($myArr, $myTest);
```

Again, several array functions can be used to return an empty or filled array. Though as someone mentioned above, the actual JS `[].every` will stop as soon as it gets a `true` return, which can save significant time if you have a large array to iterate through. I came across this question looking for a quick, functional-programing style code to iterate through just three array items.

Answer (score -1):

My case was I needed to check an array to know if all its values were numbers returning **true** if all went well. In case there was a string or something else the function had to return **false**

```
protected function checkIsNumber($arrayNumbers = []) {
    $ga = NULL;
    foreach($arrayNumbers as $value) { 
        if(is_null($ga)) {
            $ga = is_numeric(trim($value));
        } else {
            $ga = $ga === is_numeric(trim($value));
        }
    }
    
    return $ga;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you can use :http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php.

```
array array_map ( callable $callback , array $array1 [, array $... ] )
```

Comment: I'll certainly look into that.

Comment: If used correctly, that would return an array of booleans which would need to be looped through again costing performance

Comment: `map` mutates your array. If you have an array 

```$a = (1, 2, 3, 4)```


 and you use map:


```$b = array_map("is_even", $a)```


Your original array is changed:  


```//$a is now (False, True, False, True)```

Comment: @BrandonBrickyKerr that's the opposite of how `array_map` works. It's specifically for when you want to build a new array, not mutate your old one.

Comment: @BrandonBrickyKerr It doesn't modify the original array, it maps it to a new array. If you assign the same variable a new value, that's a different story.

Answer (score -3):

I wrote this protoype a LONG time ago, back in the dark age of the internet when you never knew what a the browser would do.

Yes, this predates jQuery by a decade.

It's in JS. Use it as a good exercise to learn PHP when you convert this.

A bit late for you but I hope it helps a bit.

```
  if ( typeof Array.prototype.every !== 'function' )
  {
  Array.every = Array.prototype.every = function( _callBack, _array )
  {
      // Assume failure
      var _matches = false;

      if ( typeof _callBack === 'function' )
      {
          // Use ARRAY Object data or passed in data
          _array = (_array === undefined) ? this : _array;

          // Assume success
          _matches = true;

          var _len = this.length;
          for ( var _i = 0; _i < _len; _i++ )
          {
              // If this failed, bounce out
              if ( ! _callBack(this[_i], _i, _array ) )
                  {
                  _matches = false;
                  break;
              }
          }
      }

      return _matches;
  };
```

}