# JUnit: Is there a way to assert all array values at once?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest, assertj

I have a map in which its values are a simple pojo.
For example (in a very loosely code):

```
Class Data{
  int a;
  Boolean b;
}

Map<Integer, Data> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Now the map is being populated with values.
And at then end I would like to assert that all the b values of the data object of all map entries are, for example, true.

So I tried something like that:

```
private void computeAllBooleans(){

    allBooleansStatus = true;
    myMap.values()
        .forEach(data ->
            allBooleansStatus = allBooleansStatus && data.getB();
}
```

1. Is there a more concise way to achieve that?
2. Is there a way to assert it with JUnit (or other relevant frameworks like hamcrest, assertj, etc.) assertions?

(I noticed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829780/checking-all-array-values-at-once) but didn't understand how can I use the suggested answers there...)

Comment: Probably you need to use `allMatch` like this: `myMap.values().stream().allMatch(data ->data.getB().equals(true));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `allMatch` terminal operation to check all element of map like this:

```
myMap.values().stream().allMatch(Data::getB);
```

or use filter and count it like this:

```
myMap.values().stream().filter(Data::getB).count() == myMap.size();
```

Comment: Of course you have to place this code inside an `assert` call: `assertTrue( myMap.values().stream().allMatch( Data::getB ) )`. For the second approach, it has to be done accordingly.

Comment: Or `myMap.values().forEach(data -> assertTrue(data.getB()) );`

Comment: Better use AssertJ `allMatch` in this case: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#allMatch(java.util.function.Predicate,java.lang.String)

Comment: Using AssertJ is much preferable. Code is cleaner and assertion error messages are way more descriptive.

Answer (score 3):

With [AssertJ Core](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core) you can chain [`extracting`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#extracting(java.util.function.Function)) and [`containsOnly`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#containsOnly(ELEMENT...)):

```
Map<Integer, Data> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put(1, new Data(1, true));
myMap.put(2, new Data(2, true));
myMap.put(3, new Data(3, true));

assertThat(myMap.values()).extracting(Data::getB).containsOnly(true);
```

The benefit of using AssertJ is also a nicely formatted error message in case of failures. For example, the following:

```
Map<Integer, Data> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put(1, new Data(1, true));
myMap.put(2, new Data(2, false));
myMap.put(3, new Data(3, false));

assertThat(myMap.values()).extracting(Data::getB).containsOnly(true);
```

would fail with:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting ArrayList:
  [true, false, false]
to contain only:
  [true]
but the following element(s) were unexpected:
  [false, false]
```

More `Iterable` assertions are described in the [official documentation](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-group-assertions).

Answer (score 2):

you can use more elegant way with the **assertj** library using **allMatch** or **allSatisfy**:

https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-group-satisfy

```
List<TolkienCharacter> hobbits = list(frodo, sam, pippin);

// all elements must satisfy the given assertions
assertThat(hobbits).allSatisfy(character -> {
  assertThat(character.getRace()).isEqualTo(HOBBIT);
  assertThat(character.getName()).isNotEqualTo("Sauron");
});
```